# How to do synchronous cross-domain call in javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am doing cross domain call.
This is taking more time(some ms or 1s).

so below that code is executing.

```
var xdr;
    if (window.XDomainRequest) // Check whether the browser supports XDR. 
    {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Create a new XDR object.
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
                var data = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                AddData(data, link);
            };
            xdr.open("post", urlSearch);
            xdr.send();
        }
        else {
            alert('Server Error!! Try Later.');
        }
    }
    else {
         alert("Not IE 8");
     }
```

I want to do that synchronous.
So that after that call finished below code will execute

please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [`async : false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here, though x-domain req is another concern.

Comment: What @moonwave99 said: "Cross-domain requests and dataType: 'jsonp' requests do not support synchronous operation."

Comment: do async:true...it will work

Comment: It's not at all about jQuery ajax requests like $.ajax or $.get. It is about the IE proprietary XDomainRequest that doesn't support synchronous requests

Comment: `async:false` has been deprecated, due to the fact that 99.9% of the time there's actually no need for synchronous calls.  If the OP explains why it *needs* to be synchronous then we can probably help explain a better way to do it.

Comment: how to do the async :false in this case.

This is a ajax syntax.
for cross domain ajax how to do this.

can you please the full code please.

Comment: You can switch to $.ajax with dataType "jsonp" which will allow cross domain requests

Comment: In my case the servlet is taking more time to serv(Give data).

so below function is executing before finish this.

In that function i am fetching.

it is not showing any data because it is trying to fetch data before insert.

So i want synchronous call

Comment: Server is giving json object. and i have to do post request which is not possible in jsonp.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You need to process the code of your "function" (or rather call the function from) inside the onload (or success) callback of your request. This will make sure that you can access the request result

Comment: devnull69 Sorry i didn't what you want to share.
Sorry

Comment: we can't made this synchronous ???

Comment: @devnull69 It is impossible to make JSONP synchronous. And how it is even related to the question? Receiving +1 for nothing? Stackoverflow, please wake up.

Comment: @user1811989 Noone should help you with that ( I doubt it is even possible, but I might be wrong ). Simply because making AJAX synchronous blocks entire browser and is a root of all evil. Learn JavaScript and refactor your code so it is Asynchronous.

Comment: Try this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541977/any-way-to-simulate-a-synchronous-xdomainrequest-xdr-request/23248704#23248704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, since some "JavaScript" programmers tend to be actually jQuery programmers ( and I doubt that they can even be that, I'm talking about comments ).

Back to the topic. After few minutes of googling it seems that XDomainRequest object **does not** support synchronous calls.

And this is actually good. What you don't know is that synchronous AJAX ( note that synchronous AJAX is a contradiction on its own - first A stands for Asynchronous ) is **the root of all evil** in browsers. Why? Because JavaScript is single-threaded, so when user waits for a request to finish he **can't do** anything - entire page is blocked ( and in some worse cases, like IE8 I believe, entire browser is blocked ).

So what should you do? You should do what every good JavaScript programmer does and write your code in an asynchronous way. For example:

```
var xdr;
if (window.XDomainRequest) { // Check whether the browser supports XDR. 
    xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Create a new XDR object.
    xdr.onload = function () {
        var data = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
        AddData(data, link);
        // other code goes here
    };
    xdr.onerror = function () {
        alert('Server Error!! Try Later.');
    };
    xdr.open("post", urlSearch);
    xdr.send();
} else {
    alert("Not IE 8");
}
```

If you have more code that depends on `xdr`, then simply add it to `onload` handler ( you can wrap it in a separate function to make it easier to read ).

Comment: thanks freakish for nice answer.
its really helpful for me.
let me try to add all code in the load event if it is not possible than i will inform you later.


one query:- Is there any other way to solve this problem 
means:- The process i mentioned may not be right approach to the problem.

Thanks a ton for this information.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of this answer, and while in most cases Async makes sense, there are some occasions where it just doesn't work. For example, I'm implementing a FB signin button. Unless I load the JS on the page at startup (which I don't do because it might not be used), when a user clicks the button, i have to load the FB.js file before calling a function in that script that triggers a popup. If I asynchronously load the JS, I have to pass a callback, but many browsers block popups that come from anonymous functions. It has to be directly downstream from a click.